# Oracle query using Xpath to get comma separated List for same node

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, oracle11g

*Hello Everyone,
I need a help to fetch comma separated list for same node if exists in XML nodes.
My XML is like this which is stored in my database:-*

```
<Event>
    <Detail>
        <List>
            <Element>
                <name>ABC</name>
                <salary>150</salary>
            </Element>
            <Element>
                <name>PQR</name>
                <salary>250</salary>
            </Element>
        </List>
    </Detail>
</Event>
```

*I need to get comma separated name list  (ABC,PQR ) from this using xpath oracle query.
I have tried alot and when i get a way like this :-*

```
NVL(VALUE (line).EXTRACT ('/Event/Detail/List/Element/name/text()') .getstringval (),'') Name List
```

Then , my output was ABCPQR.

No Space or comma was there. Could anyone please help me out for this .

**Expected output is :- ABC,PQR**

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

You're pulling a list of values out of an XML document, rather than a single value, so I think you'd be better off selecting them all into a table using `XMLTABLE` and then joining them together with `LISTAGG`.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE xmltest (id INTEGER, x XMLTYPE);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO xmltest (id, x) VALUES (1, XMLTYPE('<Event>
  2      <Detail>
  3          <List>
  4              <Element>
  5                  <name>ABC</name>
  6                  <salary>150</salary>
  7              </Element>
  8              <Element>
  9                  <name>PQR</name>
 10                  <salary>250</salary>
 11              </Element>
 12          </List>
 13      </Detail>
 14  </Event>'));

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT t.id, LISTAGG(y.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM)
  2    FROM xmltest t,
  3         XMLTABLE('//Element' PASSING t.x COLUMNS name VARCHAR2(1000) PATH 'name') y
  4   GROUP BY t.id;

        ID
----------
LISTAGG(Y.NAME,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYROWNUM)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1
ABC,PQR
```

There is a function in XPath 2.0, `string-join`, which will join the string values together with commas.  It would seem to be just what you need, but alas it seems Oracle doesn't support it.