# Oracle XMLQuery- Display comma separated list with two XML nodes

Tags: oracle, xpath, oracle11g, oracle-xml-db

I have a query such as this-

```
WITH xtbl AS (SELECT xmltype ('<root>
                    <parent>
                        <item>
                            <item_detail>AAA</item_detail>
                            <item_amount>1000</item_amount>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <item_detail>BBB</item_detail>
                            <item_amount>2000</item_amount>
                        </item>
                    </parent>
                </root>') AS xcol FROM dual)
SELECT xmlcast (
           xmlquery ('root/parent/string-join[item/item_detail/text()]' PASSING xcol RETURNING CONTENT) AS VARCHAR2 (2000))
           AS item_details
  FROM xtbl;
```

Although the example specified above contains an  node, in my real problem not every `<parent>` node will contain an `<item>` node. Thus I cannot use the XMLTable solution as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025570/oracle-query-using-xpath-to-get-comma-separated-list-for-same-node) answer.

The `SELECT xmlcast(...` query is what I have tried so far above and it isn't working. My expected output is this-

```
ITEM_DETAILS
------------------
AAA 1000, BBB 2000
```

Please suggest how I can modify my XMLQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an XMLTable call still:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM xtbl
CROSS JOIN xmltable('/root/parent/item'
       PASSING xcol
       COLUMNS item_detail VARCHAR2(10) path 'item_detail',
               item_amount NUMBER path 'item_amount'
) x;

ITEM_DETAI ITEM_AMOUNT
---------- -----------
AAA               1000
BBB               2000
```

and then concatenate and aggregate:

```
SELECT listagg(x.item_detail ||' '|| x.item_amount, ', ')
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY item_num) AS item_details
FROM xtbl
CROSS JOIN xmltable('/root/parent/item'
       PASSING xcol
       COLUMNS item_detail VARCHAR2(10) path 'item_detail',
               item_amount NUMBER path 'item_amount',
               item_num FOR ORDINALITY
) x;

ITEM_DETAILS                                      
--------------------------------------------------
AAA 1000, BBB 2000
```

For a parent with no items that will just return null.

However, you can also do it with an XMLQuery call:

```
SELECT xmlquery(
  'let $d :=
     for $i in /root/parent/item
       return concat($i/item_detail, " ", $i/item_amount)
   return string-join($d, ", ")'
  PASSING xcol
  RETURNING CONTENT
) AS item_details
FROM xtbl;

ITEM_DETAILS                                      
--------------------------------------------------
AAA 1000, BBB 2000
```

and again with a parent with no items that just returns null.

The `let $d :=` part concatenates the detail and amount for each item, with a space between them, using `concat()`. Then all the `$d` values that generates are aggregated using `string-join()`.

That returns an XMLType, so to get the result as a plain string you can use XMLCast as in your question, or more simply use `.getStringVal()`:

```
SELECT xmlquery(
  ...
).getStringVal() AS item_details
FROM xtbl;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH xtbl AS (SELECT xmltype ('<root>
                    <parent>
                        <item>
                            <item_detail>AAA</item_detail>
                            <item_amount>1000</item_amount>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <item_detail>BBB</item_detail>
                            <item_amount>2000</item_amount>
                        </item>
                    </parent>
                </root>') AS xcol FROM dual)
SELECT xmlcast (
           xmlquery (
           'string-join(/root/parent/item/string-join((*), " "), ", ")' 
           PASSING xcol
           RETURNING CONTENT) AS VARCHAR2 (2000)
       )
       AS item_details
  FROM xtbl;
```

EDIT:
There isn't anything special there with *. It is the short hand for `child::*`

The inner string-join:
`/root/parent/item/string-join(child::*, " ")` joins the values of each child element of `/root/parent/item` (here it refers to `<item_detail>` and `<item_amount>`. the delimiter is a `space`.

outer string-join for its part, joins the results of each inner string-join with the limiter of a `comma`.

EDIT-2:

```
'string-join(/root/parent/item/string-join(
                                           (item_detail, item_amount)
                                           , " "
                                          )
             , ", "
            )'
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. What is the significance of `*` in `string-join((*)...`?

Comment: updated. pls see the edit. Try changing the delimiter for each string-join() and test it out.

Comment: Is it possible to qualify the nodes instead of just using `*`? How is it done?